# Поясните разницу в mbstring версии функции PHP и обычной?

Tags: php

Поясните, пожалуйста! Тестил тестил но так и не понял разницу между функциями типа mb_substr и аналогичной mb_strlen
Я понял что те что с mb вроде как для работы с UTF-8 символами.
То есть я так понимаю что в частности русские буквы они кодируются 2-мя символами, то-есть двумя байтами.
Вижу что работа и тех и других функций даёт один и тот же результат, а для того чтобы например русский текст переводить вверхний или нижний регист используется локаль и в этом вопросе mb как я понял значения не имеет, тогда не совсем понял это алиас просто что-ли для совместимости или какая то разница всё же есть?

Comment: У вас вопрос про разницу функций mb_substr и mb_strlen или различия между mb_* функциями и их аналогами без префикса?

Answer (score 6):

Я не знаю как вы тестили, но даже банальный пример расставляет все по местам:

```
$str = "Некий текст, который нужно обрезать до 10 символов";

echo substr($str, 0, 10); //Некий
echo "<br />";
echo strlen($str); //90
echo "<br />";
echo mb_substr($str, 0, 10); //Некий текс
echo "<br />";
echo mb_strlen($str); //50
```

Таким образом, для строк с кириллицей (да и вообще мультибайтовых строк) нужно использовать функции **mb_***. По всему остальному ваши "догадки" верны.